# Android Studio: gradle's experimental plugin and ProGuard's files

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, proguard, gradle-experimental

I use `gradle`'s experimental plugin in order to add some `NDK` code.
before usage of `NDK` support my `buildTypes` section was next

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

as you can see here I use optimized options of ProGuard.
And when I started to use `gradle`'s experimental plugin I changed those lines to

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
        }
    }
```

The question is next: is it ok to use such options when I want to use `'proguard-android-optimize.txt'` file?

If not then how I could define that I want to use `'proguard-android-optimize.txt'` file with `gradle`'s experimental plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue recently, and found that Gradle Experimental doesn't appear to include any version of ProGuard config by default, and there's no "getDefaultProguardFile()" method to call.

I've had to resort to adding the 'proguard-android-optimize.txt' file to my project for now (and referencing it in my build.gradle), as my project won't build without at least the basic rules being specified.

I'm using Gradle Experimental 0.7.2.

Comment: thanks for your answer, as for me I just copied lines from `proguard-android-optimize.txt` to my `proguard-rules.pro` file